# Animation doesn't update when switching action strip in 2.91

Tags: animation, nla-editor, actions

I'm not sure if this is a bug in newer blender versions, or some option that needs to be enabled. In the past when I would move up or down in animation layer, the rig/animation would change immediately. Now I have to either select bones or move the action strip to force it to change to the new animation. The issue affects any scenes I've been making since 2.91.